# How do i get or sort a java json array in soccer statistics using java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, api

In the code below, the JSON objects and key `match_hometeam_score` only deliver to me an undesired result. I just want to print out all the Chelsea scores and separate them from the Arsenal scores. I haven't been able to do that. I don't want to print out Chelsea and Arsenal scores together.

```
[
{
"match_id": "218349",
"country_id": "165",
"country_name": "Europe",
"league_id": "590",
"league_name": "Europa League",
"match_date": "2019-05-29",
"match_status": "Finished",
"match_time": "21:00",
"match_hometeam_id": "2616",
"match_hometeam_name": "Chelsea",
"match_hometeam_score": "4",
"match_awayteam_id": "2617",
"match_awayteam_name": "Arsenal",
"match_awayteam_score": "1",
"match_hometeam_halftime_score": "0",
"match_awayteam_halftime_score": "0",
"match_live": "0"
},
{
"match_id": "167631",
"country_id": "41",
"country_name": "ENGLAND",
"league_id": "148",
"league_name": "Premier League",
"match_date": "2019-01-19",
"match_status": "Finished",
"match_time": "18:30",
"match_hometeam_id": "2617",
"match_hometeam_name": "Arsenal",
"match_hometeam_score": "2",
"match_awayteam_id": "2616",
"match_awayteam_name": "Chelsea",
"match_awayteam_score": "0",
"match_hometeam_halftime_score": "2",
"match_awayteam_halftime_score": "0",
"match_live": "0"
},
{
"match_id": "114836",
"country_id": "41",
"country_name": "ENGLAND",
"league_id": "148",
"league_name": "Premier League",
"match_date": "2018-08-18",
"match_status": "Finished",
"match_time": "18:30",
"match_hometeam_id": "2616",
"match_hometeam_name": "Chelsea",
"match_hometeam_score": "3",
"match_awayteam_id": "2617",
"match_awayteam_name": "Arsenal",
"match_awayteam_score": "2",
"match_hometeam_halftime_score": "",
"match_awayteam_halftime_score": "",
"match_live": "0"
},
{
"match_id": "70876",
"country_id": "41",
"country_name": "ENGLAND",
"league_id": "8640",
"league_name": "Carabao Cup",
"match_date": "2018-01-24",
"match_status": "Finished",
"match_time": "21:00",
"match_hometeam_id": "2617",
"match_hometeam_name": "Arsenal",
"match_hometeam_score": "2",
"match_awayteam_id": "2616",
"match_awayteam_name": "Chelsea",
"match_awayteam_score": "1",
"match_hometeam_halftime_score": "1",
"match_awayteam_halftime_score": "1",
"match_live": "0"
},
{
"match_id": "68621",
"country_id": "41",
"country_name": "ENGLAND",
"league_id": "8640",
"league_name": "Carabao Cup",
"match_date": "2018-01-10",
"match_status": "Finished",
"match_time": "21:00",
"match_hometeam_id": "2616",
"match_hometeam_name": "Chelsea",
"match_hometeam_score": "0",
"match_awayteam_id": "2617",
"match_awayteam_name": "Arsenal",
"match_awayteam_score": "0",
"match_hometeam_halftime_score": "0",
"match_awayteam_halftime_score": "0",
"match_live": "0"
}
]
```

This is the JSON File. Arsenal and Chelsea's score are both printing no matter how hard I tried.

This code below is what I tried using to print out the home team:

```
int i = parentArray.length();
JSONObject json_obj = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
String name = json_obj.getString("match_hometeam_score");

if(i > 2) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

I am expecting:

```
CHELSEA = 4, 0, 3, 1, 0           
ARSENAL = 1, 2, 2, 2, 0
```

As their respective scores.

Comment: What output you are getting currently? Please, make your code [mcve]

Comment: My output is 4, 2, 3, 2, 0

Answer (score 0):

Here it is with the comments:

```
    //creating map to store list of scores for a team
    Map<String, List<String>> teamScore = new HashMap<>();
    teamScore.put("Arsenal", new LinkedList<>());
    teamScore.put("Chelsea", new LinkedList<>());


    //iterating over json array and extract teams names and scores and store 
    //scores in the map
    JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(json);
    for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json_obj = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String homeTeamName = json_obj.getString("match_hometeam_name");
        String homeTeamScore = json_obj.getString("match_hometeam_score");

        String awayTeamName = json_obj.getString("match_awayteam_name");
        String awayTeamScore = json_obj.getString("match_awayteam_score");

        teamScore.get(homeTeamName).add(homeTeamScore);
        teamScore.get(awayTeamName).add(awayTeamScore);
    }

    //printing the map
    System.out.println(teamScore);
```

Output:

```
{Arsenal=[1, 2, 2, 2, 0], Chelsea=[4, 0, 3, 1, 0]}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I separate and  assign each of those score to different variables. I want to make calculations with them.

Comment: You can access corresponding scores by iterating over list. For example `teamScore.get("Arsenal").get(0)` will get you `1` `teamScore.get("Arsenal").get(1)` -> `2` and so on.

Comment: I deeply appreciate.